# How to convert a ruby hash with an 'array' key to a nested hash in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, key

I'm trying to figure out how i can convert a complex hash like this:

```
{
  ["A", "B"]=>{"id"=>123,"name"=>"test"},
  ["A", "F"]=>{"id"=>236,"name"=>"another test"},
  ["C", "F"]=>{"id"=>238,"name"=>"anoother test"}
}
```

into an even more complex hash like

```
{
  "A"=>{
     "B"=>{"id"=>123,"name"=>"test"},
     "F"=>{"id"=>236,"name"=>"another test"}
  },
  "C"=>{
     "F"=>{"id"=>238,"name"=>"anoother test"}
  }
}
```

Any help would be really welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`each_with_object` could be the rescue:

```
hash.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = {}}) do |((first, last), v), memo|  
  memo[first].merge!(last => v)
end
#=> {"A"=>{"B"=>{"id"=>123, "name"=>"test"}, 
#          "F"=>{"id"=>236, "name"=>"another test"}}, 
#    "C"=>{"F"=>{"id"=>238, "name"=>"anoother test"}}}
```

Comment: Instead of doing it yourself with `Array#{first/last}` you can tell Ruby to decompose `k`: `|((k1, k2), v), memo|`. Depending on the actual data you can even give it a more fitting name than `k2` (or `k.last`).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) then [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) by [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to a new hash using [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-to_h):

```
h.group_by { |h,k| h.first }.transform_values { |v| v.map { |a, b| [a.last, b] }.to_h }
```

Comment: Really nice! Great one-liner!